# In Cloud Functions, what is the syntax for writing a JSON to the Map data type in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Google Cloud Function that receives a Webhook JSON payload, parses the JSON and writes the data to the Cloud Firestore.

I have a map of strings inside of Cloud Firestore at collection.("orders").doc():

```
customerNote (map)
     customerNote1 (string)
     customerNote2 (string)
     customerNote3 (string)
```

For a simple string, the syntax for writing to the Cloud Firestore within Cloud Functions could like like:

```
await admin.firestore().collection("orders").doc().set({
orderNameInFirestore: data.orderNamefromJSON
})
```

What does this cloud function look like for a Map of Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore can accept and store arbitrary JavaScript objects (with some limitations). As an example:

```
const myMap = {"key-one": "abc", "key-two": 123};

await admin.firestore().collection("orders").add({
  mappedData: myMap
});
```

the above will work just fine so long as the map is of reasonable size.

Comment: The data I wish to store inside a Cloud Firestore Map is coming from a Webhook JSON payload. In your example, the data within myMap is predetermined. How can I set up myMap to accept JSON payload from a Webhook?

Comment: You just pass it in. Have you actually tried doing so and there's an error? Firestore is a schemaless database - you can just pass data into it and it generally works. If you're running into an error, you should update the question with that.

Comment: do you have any suggestions for securing a cloud function like this? I'm worried about the JSON data leaking or others getting access to the cloud function URL endpoint.